# Filter for Admin Nav Menus Drop Down

Tags: menus, admin, hooks

In short, is there a filter for the Admin Panels Nav-Menu Dropdown List?

[image]

For non-administrators I need to remove access to modifying / selecting a specific menu but still allow access to other menus. I need to filter the listed menus and unset the specific "Main Menu" but am having trouble finding the correct hook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the filter you want is [`wp_get_nav_menus`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.2.2/src/wp-includes/nav-menu.php#L466):

```
function wp_get_nav_menus( $args = array() ) {
    $defaults = array( 'hide_empty' => false, 'orderby' => 'name' );
    $args = wp_parse_args( $args, $defaults );

     /**
     * Filter the navigation menu objects being returned.
     *
     * @since 3.0.0
     *
     * @see get_terms()
     *
     * @param array $menus An array of menu objects.
     * @param array $args  An array of arguments used to retrieve menu objects.
     */
    return apply_filters( 'wp_get_nav_menus', get_terms( 'nav_menu',  $args), $args );
}
```

The `wp_get_nav_menus()` function is used on line 383 of `wp-admin-nav-menus.php` to set the `$nav_menus` variable which is used throughout the file in a number of places, so be very careful what you do.

Comment: Perfect, I was able to use this and there doesn't seem to be any side-effects... yet.